# Need help selecting a transformer for an AC/DC converter

Tags: power-supply, transformer, ac-dc

I'm working on a pinball project that requires a 50VDC voltage to drive solenoids. The biggest load comes from the flippers (which both could be activated simultaneously) however it's possible for additional coils to fire at the same time (multiple balls on the playfield at the same time). This voltage can be unregulated, and the exact voltage isn't critical.

I could use some help in selecting a transformer as I find a lot of conflicting anecdotal statements for other DIY builders that does not make sense to me.

For background to understand the circuit, in a pinball game the flippers are controlled by a solenoid that has two windings. A high power for the kick, and then another goes in series to hold the flipper up. This is done mechanically by an end of stroke (EOS) switch being opened to tie in the second coil.

Now, the power coil is only 4 ohms giving a current of 12.5A which is pretty hefty, and as I mentioned there is a possibility of both flippers being engaged at the same time for 25A total. This would be momentary, milliseconds. However also repetitive.

From what I understand, transformers are rated at RMS and this would be in the US (120V, 60 Hz). So a 40V transformer would give me about 40 * 1.414 = 56.56 volts. The bridge rectifier would eat up another ~2V giving me 54V. I think I could get away with a 35V transformer giving me ~47.5 volts after the bridge rectifier. A lower voltage should give me a higher current at the same VA rating correct?

What I'm having trouble with though is what VA rating to go for. It seems like a 35V RMS transformer at 25A I should need around 875VA of power available. Is that correct? The contradictory information I have found is people using much smaller power supplies, do they just get less force out of the solenoids? A supplier of toroidal transformers I've found with reasonable prices offers 800VA ($84), 1000VA ($100), and 1500VA ($155) options. They're not exactly cheap though so I want to make sure I get it right while not going overboard to keep the budget down.

Thanks!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL6ePg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I'm pretty sure these coils should all be AC, not DC.

Comment: I think that all your considerations/2v picking etc. are inconsequential (you forgot coil losses, inrush control, etc. etc,) you won't be able to design a working PSU this way. I would strongly suggest to look at open-frame industrial-grade PSU with 48V rating, like Mean Well USA model RSP-1500-48. It is very likely that smaller PSU will do the job, with extra capacitors. At the end it will cost you a lot less than your own research and development.

Comment: @Janka Older electromechanical (EM) machines used AC coils, but they switched to DC with the solid state machines around the 80's.

Comment: Are you sure about the latter? It's also possible to drive these "DC" coils with about 500Hz square waves. That would increase their impedance a lot and limit the current.

Comment: @Janka I'm 100% sure, they come pre-installed with a flyback diode which would be very bad if AC. Plus schematics of the older machines are readily available. The transformers they used are not though. Limiting the current limits the power, don't forget they're hitting a steel ball uphill!